# Short-hand or Efficiency for the following code

Tags: javascript, jquery, case, shorthand, performance

This is my first question here on Stack Overflow. I generally find all my answers from searching but I'm completely out of motivation after writing the following code.

Is there a more efficient way or short-hand to write the following code?

Currently it does exactly what I want. When you click a radio button a div is loaded next to that radio button. If you switch the radio button it removes the div and creates a new one next to that radio button.

I'm fairly new to actually writing my own JavaScript/jQuery. I know about CASE but I'm not entirely sure if this is a good situation for that.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var checkedItem = true;

$('form input').click(function(){

    if (checkedItem == true){
        $(this).siblings('div.next').remove('.checked');
        $(this).after('<div class="next">NEXT</div>');
        $(this).siblings('div.next').addClass('checked');

        checkedItem = false;

    }
    else {
        $(this).siblings('div.next').remove('.checked');
        $(this).after('<div class="next">NEXT</div>');
        $(this).siblings('div.next').addClass('checked');

        checkedItem = true;     
    }

});

 });


    <form id="input-form">
<input class="PAD" type="radio" name="Seasons" value="Spring-Fall" /> Spring-Fall<br />
<input class="PAD" type="radio" name="Seasons" value="Winter" /> Winter
</form>
```

Comment: in jquery selection, you dont have to do things like "div.next". If it has the class next, just use ".next"

Comment: Are you looking for something more efficient to write and easier to read, or more efficient at run-time? Also, the first three lines inside the `if` are exactly the same as the first three lines inside the `else` branch - is that a mistake?

Comment: Multiple calls to `$(this)` are very inefficient, create a single reference and use that, e.g. `var input = $(this);` then use `input` everywhere you've used `$(this)`.

Comment: ... or, with strategic use of `.end()`, `$(this)` will chain.

Comment: Beetroot- Took your advice and chained with SpYk3HH answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on jQuery 1.7+ you can:

> HTML

```
<form id="input-form">
    <input class="PAD" type="radio" name="Seasons" value="Spring-Fall" /> 
    Spring-Fall<br />
    <input class="PAD" type="radio" name="Seasons" value="Winter" /> Winter
</form>
```

> jQuery

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
        if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
            $(this).siblings('.next').remove('.checked');
            $(this).after('<div class="next">NEXT</div>');
            $(this).siblings('.next').addClass('checked');
        }
        else { // fyi, this, or your var is kinda useless redundancy, but just for purpose of show, here ya go
            $(this).siblings('.next').remove('.checked');
            $(this).after('<div class="next">NEXT</div>');
            $(this).siblings('.next').addClass('checked');
        };
    });
});
```

Although you could easily simplify the whole thing with:

```
$(function() {
    $("input[type=radio]").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings('.next').remove();
        $(this).after($("<div />").addClass("next checked").text("NEXT"));
    });
});
```

Comment: `this.checked` is both more efficient and easier to read than `$(this).is(":checked")`.

Comment: Yup thank you. I'm very tired have been working on a project all day.

Comment: _"eh, tomato tomato"_ - Well the question was specifically about efficiency. (Now if you'll excuse me, I have some potAHtoes to eat.)

Comment: "tomato tomato" - I know him well.

Comment: My point was simply, this.checked seems more efficient, till you take into account that it doesnt follow standard jQuery (so not really "easier to read" if ll the rest of your work is in jQuery) and the time difference in read/write speed is so minuscule that ... "tomāto, tomăto". it's one half dozen or the other.

Answer (score 0):

What purpose does your "checkedItem" boolean serve?

It seems a function like this would accomplish the same thing (see [http://jsfiddle.net/ZGQf3/3](http://jsfiddle.net/ZGQf3/)):

```
$('form input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    $('.next').remove('.checked')
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.after('<div class="next">NEXT</div>');
    $this.siblings('.next').addClass('checked');
});
```

You could conceivably just call remove() depending on what the rest of your DOM looks like.